# Covariance Quick Question

Tags: covariance

so I have Cov(X,Y). I was just wondering if this would allow me to find Cov(2X, 2Y)? And if so, how?

More specifically, how would this work for $Cov(e^X, e^Y)$?

Comment: $$\textrm{Cov}(2X,2Y)=E(4XY)-E(2X)E(2Y)=4E(XY)-2\times 2\times E(X)E(Y)=4\textrm{Cov}(X,Y)$$

Comment: To generalize, we have $\textrm{Cov}(aX,bY)=ab\textrm{Cov}(X,Y)$

Comment: It is just a bilinear form. Use bilinearity.

Comment: On the other hand, $\text{Cov}(e^X, e^Y)$ is a different creature entirely.

Comment: @RobertIsrael is there anywhere I can go to learn about how to make this transformation?

Comment: @JasonHuang I don't think it will work since covariance is bilinear and you have some nonlinear function. Think exp as series, you will have covariance between X and Y between all power. Additionally I'm not sure if you can extract infinite sum in bilinear form.